# Link a delegate function to an entry in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, delegates

I'm trying to link a delegate function to an entry in a DataGridView, but I don't know how to go about doing it.

[image]

If I click on "Run Selected" I would like to:

- Find the selected row
- Find the delegate function associated with that row
- Run delegate function

  ```
      public Uc_Test_Test()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      string[] row = new string[] { "Foo", "Not Executed" };
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
      row = new string[] { "Bar", "Not Executed" };
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
      row = new string[] { "FooBar", "Passed" };
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
      row = new string[] { "BarFoo", "Failed"};
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
  }

  public delegate void FooDelegate();

  public static void Foo()
  {
      // Do Foo Stuff
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your methods that you want to call after clicking on their corresponding entries in the dataGridView are static and paramatereless you will have to:

1. Get the name of the method after its entry being clicked.
2. Using reflexion you can call dynamically your method:

   ```
   typeof(Uc_Test_Test).GetMethod("Foo").Invoke(null, null);
   ```